# Create snow animation

Tags: css, automation

I've been trying to recreate the random snow/star effect that's on [this website](http://stars-agency.com/Home.html) , but I've had no luck..

I'm assuming this needs to be done in CSS, is there anyone who can help me write the code?

Thanks in advance!

Samoht

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, and we be willed to help you

Answer (score 0):

you have nothing show, but here is a short description

To create this effect, we’ll need three different “snow” graphics. These are transparent images of varying degrees of size and focus. We’ll overlay these three graphics on top of one another for a bit of depth.

Let’s style the background with these images. I’ve uploaded them to Imgur, feel free to use them.

Next, let’s create the keyframe. This is necessary to animate the background images as shown in the example down. If you’re read any of my posts before, you’re probably familiar with CSS Keyframes by now.

Our “snow” keyframe is slowly moving each background image independently of one another at different paces to create the awesome effect of snow falling.

You can change the speed or direction by modifying the background positions in the keyframe at 100%.

Demo w src: jsfiddle.net/orLgtgao/